# CSS - Display table-cell not rendering correctly with custom HTML tag

Tags: css

I've replaced `<td>` with `<custom-tag>`, and then in my CSS I have `custom-tag { display: table-cell; }`, but both Chrome and Firefox seem to remove the element from the table. **What good is display:table-cell if not for this?**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <span style="display:table-cell"></span>
    <span style="display:table-cell"></span>
    <span style="display:table-cell"></span>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The reason for not using `<td>` is I want to implement a Can.js component. But that's beside the point.

http://jsfiddle.net/zNj5C/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the other way around:

```
<div style="display: table;">
    <div style="display: table-row;">
        <span style="display:table-cell"></span>
        <span style="display:table-cell"></span>
        <span style="display:table-cell"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```